# Conditional Statement Command Syntax Error in Bash Script

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, syntax-error, unexpected-token

I ran into a command syntax issue for a conditional statement in a script that someone else wrote. The script is as follows (truncated).

```
#! /bin/bash

# app_upgrade.sh

# Verify file integrity
filehash=$( md5sum install_package.tgz )
md5hash=$( cat install_package.tgz.md5 )

if [ -z $( diff <(echo $md5hash) <(echo $filehash) ) ]; then
    printf "File Integrity Check Passed"
else
    printf "File Integrity Check Failed"
    exit
fi
```

When I run this script, it fails when trying to interpret the conditional statement due to an unexpected opening parenthesis. The exact error reported to the CLI is as follows.

```
app_upgrade.sh: command substitution: line 118: syntax error near unexpected token `('
app_upgrade.sh: command substitution: line 118: ` diff <(echo $md5hash) <(echo $filehash) )'
```

I verified that diff is an executable command on my system by the same user as that running the script. I also ran the `diff <(echo $md5hash) <(echo $filehash)` from the CLI and this worked without any issues. I also tried to escape the parentheses but that also failed. I am stumped as to why this is causing an issue.

As a workaround, I tried a few other conditionals since I would not have used diff for the comparison had I been writing the script in the first place. I tried the following replacements for the conditional specified in the script above.

`if [ "$filehash" = "$md5hash" ]` However, this did not work. Even though the hashes were the same, the conditional caused the comparison to fail unexpectedly.

`if [[ "$filehash" == "$md5hash" ]]` This finally worked.

In summary, my questions are:

1. Why did the script fail with a syntax error when trying to interpret the `$( diff <(echo $md5hash) <(echo $filehash)` within the original conditional statement?
2. In my updated conditional statements, assuming both hashes are the same, why did `if [ "$filehash" = "$md5hash" ]` fail but `if [[ "$filehash" == "$md5hash" ]]` succeed? From my research, it looks like both are valid ways of comparing strings in bash.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put double qutoes around `$(diff ...)`

Comment: `if cmp -s <(md5sum install_package.tgz) <(cat install_package.tgz.md5); then foo; else bar; fi` Maybe.

Comment: The whole script could be reduced into `if md5sum -c install_package.tgz.md5 >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo "File Integrity Check Passed"; else echo "File Integrity Check Failed"; exit; fi`

Comment: You don't appear to actually be using `bash` to execute your script, and the process substitution isn't recognized. If you use something like `sh app_upgrade.sh ...`, the shebang is ignored.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for your comment. This pointed me in the right direction as I did think there was something shell related here causing my issue. Other users could execute this script without issues on the same system but I would fail with syntax error. See my update posted to the original question above.

Comment: Note that `noexec`  doesn't *ignore* `sh` and `bash` so much as it isn't applicable, as `sh` and `bash` aren't stored in `/home`, unlike `app_upgrade.sh`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for the correction. I was regurgitating was explained to me from the sys admin who was likely generalizing for brevity. I have updated my update above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was shell related. The root cause of my issue was a `noexec` security constraint in the /home/ directory so I could not run `./app_upgrade.sh` from there. However, `sh app_upgrade.sh` worked fine and executed the script, but I was not running it as bash as I intended. Using `bash app_upgrade.sh` allowed the script to run properly. So the root cause here was a permissions issue in the directory I was executing the script from causing me to incorrectly execute the bash script with the `sh` command.

In summary:

`[user@host ~]$ ./app_upgrade.sh` resulted in `bash: ./app_upgrade.sh: Permission denied`

`[user@host ~]$ sh app_upgrade.sh` executed the script but not as bash so this caused an issue interpreting one of the lines of code properly.

`[user@host ~]$ bash app_upgrade.sh` executed the script properly without errors.

Had I originally run this in a directory that did not have `noexec` constraint then the issue would never have manifested.

Thanks for the all the comments, suggestions and help!

Answer (score 0):

When you run your script against [`shellcheck` linter](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck#shellcheck---a-shell-script-static-analysis-tool) you can see the error

> ```
> In ./test.sh line 9:
> if [ -z $( diff <(echo $md5hash) <(echo $filehash) ) ]; then
>         ^-- SC2046 (warning): Quote this to prevent word splitting.
>                        ^------^ SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
>                                         ^-------^ SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
> ```

You have to quote the `if` expression to avoid word splitting:

```
#! /bin/bash

# app_upgrade.sh

# Verify file integrity
filehash=$( md5sum install_package.tgz )
md5hash=$( cat install_package.tgz.md5 )

# mind the `"` quotation marks around 
if [ -z "$( diff <(echo $md5hash) <(echo $filehash) )" ]; then
    printf "File Integrity Check Passed"
else
    printf "File Integrity Check Failed"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: That's warning about a potential semantic error (or syntax error raised by `[`), not a shell syntax error.

Comment: Warn about useless  `cat`:  consider: `md5hash=$(<install_package.tgz.md5)`!  (or [my ansert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75100089/1765658);-)

Comment: @Marcin Kłopotek Thanks for the shellcheck linter suggestion. I was not aware of this but that is a useful tool.